# Program to switch active window/program?

Tags: key-binding, alt-tab

I'm interested in program that can utilize additional buttons of G15, or can be bound to special hotkey like `ctrl+alt+shift+F9` in order to change active window.

Why do i need it? I'm playing game EVE-Online in 2 windows. And using alt+tab sometimes fails to winamp/vlc/any 3rd part program. Frequency of alt-tabbing: every 3-5 minutes.

And what i want:

- Dedicated program to choose "new" active program, like
  `switch-app.exe /setActive:'EVE-Online - CharName1'`
  or
  `switch-app.exe /setActive:'EVE-Online - CharName2'`
  And i'll be able to use G15 config tool to bind this commands to G-keys.
- Dedicated program which have same functionality, but with hotkey-bind system in it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Solution found: http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/

Command line tool to manipulate windows + G15 Profiler = **Exactly what i want** :)

Comment: please post it as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: http://commandline.co.uk/cmdow

Command line tool to manipulate windows + G15 Profiler = Exactly what i want :)